# Why does this Collectors.toMap have issues

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I am trying to convert a `Set<String>` into a `Map`. But I'm not sure why the `keyMapper` and `valueMapper` wont take the key functional object.

```
private static void populateHeader(Map<String, List<String>> headerMap, 
             Set<String> keys) {
          headerMap= keys.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(key -> key.toString(),parseLine(key -> key)));
    }
```

The error message is:

> Error:(83, 91) java: incompatible types: java.lang.String is not a
>   functional interface

Comment: What is the signature of `parseLine`?

Comment: modified: private static void populateHeader( Set<String> keys) {
           Map<String, List<String>> headerMap= keys.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(key -> key.toString(),parseLine(getHeaderLine(key -> key))));
       
    }
    public static List<String> parseLine(String cvsLine)...  throws Error:(83, 91) java: incompatible types: java.lang.String is not a functional interface

Comment: and what is `getHeaderLine`? please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59900537/edit) for updates.

Comment: (Not directly relevant, but should that be `csvLine` as in Comma Separated Value?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the code failed initially here is the line that worked!
For this code I get a Set of keys (Set Keys) for each key I need to load a string List of tags (That's the parseLine function). so finally return a Map of keys and its tags

...
Map> headerMap= keys.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(key -> key, key -> parseLine(getHeaderLine( key))));
...

It worked finally.
Thanks you
James

Answer (score 0):

```
      headerMap= keys.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(key -> key.toString(),parseLine(key -> key)));
```

Presumably `parseLine(key -> key)` should be `key -> parseLine(key)`. Technically `parseLine` could return a functional object of a correct type (`Function<String,String>`).

The error message would help.

You could write this as:

```
      headerMap = keys.stream().collect(
          Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), key -> parseLine(key))
      );
```

It's worth noting that `headerMap` is a parameter, so it is a little odd to be assigning it. The value passed by the calling function will be unaffected.

Comment: modified: private static void populateHeader( Set<String> keys) {
           Map<String, List<String>> headerMap= keys.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(key -> key.toString(),parseLine(getHeaderLine(key -> key))));
       
    }
    public static List<String> parseLine(String cvsLine)...  throws Error:(83, 91) java: incompatible types: java.lang.String is not a functional interface